# Testing input against dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary

I'm trying to compare a phrase a user inputs against a file (dictionary) I've imported to my program. The code I have is:

```
thesaurus = open("thesaurus.txt", "r")


phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")

for key in thesaurus:
   if key in phrase:
       print ("hello")
```

And I have tested it out by entering phrases that I know are within the file, so I should have a printed "hello" at certain points, but my program is returning nothing. I suppose the issue is with the for loop I set up.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

edit:

```
counter = 0
for key in thesaurus:
    counter = 0
    for x in range(0, len(phrase)):
        if phrase[counter] == key.rstrip():
           print ("hi")
        counter += 1
```

Comment: Is the case consistent?

Comment: `key` will include a new line.  You should use `key.rstrip()` instead.

Comment: @zondo key.rstrip() once i'm inside the for loop?

Comment: @DannyGarcia: Yes: `if key.rstrip() in phrase:`

Comment: @zondo it seems like its still doing the same thing with .rstrip() . I added an edited code above, do you think this is a better way of approaching it? (It's still doing to same thing even with the new code)

Comment: @DannyGarcia: `'ab' in 'abc'` is `True` even though not a single character in `abc` is `ab`.  You should still use `in`; just use `key.rstrip()` instead of `key`.

Comment: What is the content in thesaurus.txt? share some samples.

Comment: @Anoop thesaurus.txt is keeping a series of words like: 

abacist,numeration
aback,rear
abacus,numeration

Answer (score 0):

When you have that kind of issue, a good idea is often to look at the values you are trying to compare.

For instance:

```
for key in thesaurus:
    print(repr(key))
```

This shows that keys end with a `\n` character. Hence, they cannot be in your phrase.

Try using `key.rstrip()` instead, it's a method to remove whitespaces at the right of the string.

Comment: would i have to open the file as a dictionary to be able to get the text within it to act as a key? or is how i opened it above fine?

Comment: You can't open the file as a dictionary. If you want to, you can read it as a list and convert that list to a dictionary, but I don't see the point here